# How check linux framebuffer changes fastly

Tags: c, embedded-linux, iot, framebuffer

I have a `Qt` application on an embedded Linux without `X`. I would like to see the screen remotely and I cannot use `VNC` or other solutions. Therefore,  I am implementing it myself. I need to send a framebuffer to a remote server when there is a change on the framebuffer. What I do is to continuously copying the framebuffer (`fb0.raw`) and check if it is different from the previously copied framebuffer(`fb0_old.raw`) and if they are different then I send the framebuffer. Here is the pseudo code of what I am doing:

```
cp /dev/fb0 /fb0.raw
if (diff -q fb0_old.raw fb0.raw) != "":
   send(fb0.raw)
   mv fb0.raw fb0_old.raw
```

This code takes almost `0.5` seconds to execute on my embedded linux and if the network delay and time for other prosses added to this, then it becomes too slow. Is there a faster way to check if the framebuffer has changed without continuously copying it? 
It doesn't matter if it is in kernel or user space or if this is a pure `C` or `bash` or ..

Comment: diff is probably not the right tool for the task, since it tries to generate a "patch". If your goal is just sending the framebuffer, pipe it through some high efficiency video encoder; among the first steps is discarding all those parts in an image, that didn't change. Then just stream the resulting video to the remote machine.

Comment: @datenwolf thanks for the help. I have zero experience with high efficiency video encoders, could you please just name a few of them?

Comment: h264, VP9/WebP, etc. Just the standard stuff you'd normally use for regular video files. You can use regular ffmpeg as a frontend. Use the `image2` input format, configure size and pixel format to match the fbdev configuration, read from stdin, where you simply pipe in the contents of fb0 in a loop.

Comment: Remember to configure these codecs for low latency operation. It can have a huge effect.